# Initialize boost::fusion::map values

Tags: c++, boost, fusion

I have a `boost::fusion::map` like this:

```
struct bar {};
struct baz {};

template<typename... Args>
struct foo
{
    foo(bar &, baz &) {}
};

template<typename... T>
using MapEntry = boost::fusion::pair<boost::mpl::set<T...>, foo<T...>>;

using Map = boost::fusion::map<
            MapEntry<int, bool, double>,
            MapEntry<std::string>,
            MapEntry<int64_t, uint32_t>,
            MapEntry<char, uint64_t>
            // ...
            >;
```

then need to initialize instanse of `Map`, passing `bar_` and `baz_` into all `foo` constructors.

At the moment, I have :

```
int main()
{
    bar bar_;
    baz baz_;

    Map map_(
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<int, bool, double>>(foo<int, bool, double>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<std::string>>(foo<std::string>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<int64_t, uint32_t>>(foo<int64_t, uint32_t>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<char, uint64_t>>(foo<char, uint64_t>(bar_, baz_))
        // ...
    );

    return 0;
}
```

But this is very redundant. Is it possible to make this code cleaner ?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible ? What did you try ? Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: At now i found only `Map map_(
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<int, bool, double>>(foo<int, bool, double>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<std::string>>(foo<std::string>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<int64_t, uint32_t>>(foo<int64_t, uint32_t>(bar_, baz_)),
        boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<char, uint64_t>>(foo<char, uint64_t>(bar_, baz_))
        // ...
    );` but it too redundant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first create a function to create `MapEntry`

```
template<typename E, typename... Args>
E make_map_entry(Args &&...args)
{
    return boost::fusion::make_pair<E::first_type>(E::second_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

At second create a function to create `Map`, it uses helper function that unroll `make_map_entry` for each entry

```
template<typename M, std::size_t ...I, typename... Args>
M make_map_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, Args &&...args)
{
    return M(make_map_entry<boost::fusion::result_of::value_at_c<M, I>::type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)...);
}

template<typename M, typename... Args>
M make_map(Args &&...args)
{
    return make_map_impl<M>(std::make_index_sequence<boost::fusion::result_of::size<M>::value> {}, args...);
}
```

then we can write

```
int main()
{
    bar bar_;
    baz baz_;

    Map map(make_map<Map>(bar_, baz_));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom entry factory:

```
struct bound_factory {
    bar& bar_;
    baz& baz_;

    template <typename... T> auto entry() const {
         return boost::fusion::make_pair<boost::mpl::set<T...>>(foo<T...>(bar_, baz_));
    }
};
```

Which you could then use as follows:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0daa3ba5ec5b1d01)</kbd>**

```
int main()
{
    bar bar_;
    baz baz_;

    bound_factory f { bar_, baz_ };

    Map map_(
        f.entry<int, bool, double>(),
        f.entry<std::string>(),
        f.entry<int64_t, uint32_t>(),
        f.entry<char, uint64_t>()
    );
}
```

> #### Clippy Mode
>
> It looks as if you might be creating a Dependency Injection framework. Please be aware of this rather nice library proposal: [Boost DI](https://github.com/boost-experimental/di) [image]

Comment: Good, but need to describe types for map entries twice.